# Python Script plugin of Notepad++ not working

Tags: python, plugins, notepad++

There is a problem when I try to run Notepad++ with Python Script plugin.
I downloaded the latest versions of both, v6.5 of Notepad++ and v0.92 of Python Script plugin. 
However the two reject to work together, throwing the error:

> This ANSI plugin is not compatible with your Unicode Notepad++. This
>   plugin is not compatible with current version of Notepad++.

As I see it there is no supported ANSI version of Notepad++ anymore, so what can I do to make Python Script work again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the latest Notepad++ 6.5 Unicode and downloaded from the *Plugin Manager* the latest Python Script plugin 0.9.2.0, was installed properly and seems to work. In case you tried to install it manually, try it from the Plugin Manager, if it was the other way around, try both the PythonScript_min_0.9.2.0 and PythonScript_full_0.9.2.0 from [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npppythonscript/files/Python%20Script%200.9.2.0/).

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. I in fact did download and install the plugin manually since the firewall around here does block notepad++s plugin manager.

Answer (score 1):

Three options:

1. Find a Unicode version of the plug-in
2. Modify the existing plug-in yourself and *ideally* share it back.
3. Use an older version of Notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same error. It is probably because that you have got the wrong download.

For my case, at first I download the file **PythonScript_TclTk_1.0.8.0.7z** . This is not the right version to be install manually (by copying the extracted zip to the plugin folder of Notepad++). In fact, the structure is completely different. I still not check what this version is supposed to do.

You will need to get the full version, like :**PythonScript_Full_1.0.8.0.zip**, then extract and install manually. A quick way to check is that if you don't have a file dll like `pythonXX.dll` in the zip folder, then it is probably not the right plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You might have downloaded the .zip file. Try downloading and installing through .msi installer. 
That worked for me.